# Jquery Token Input not populating values from database, in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-tokeninput

I am new to jQuery Token Input and am learning through [this](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) tutorial.

**What I want to do ?**

I want to show values from database as the user types in the value into the textbox using jQuery Token input.

**What have I tried so far ?**

So far, this is what my view looks like...

**View**

```
<p>
Getting data from database using <i>token Input</i> =>
<input type="text" id="selectDb" />
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#selectDb").tokenInput("@Url.Action("Search")");

    });
</script> 

</div>
```

and below is my controller action.

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Search(string q)
{
    var searchResult = Helper.SearchContact(q);
    return Json(searchResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and my Helper.cs class code is...

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static CRUDEntities1 Entities = new CRUDEntities1();

    public static IEnumerable<Contact> SearchContact(string s)
    {
        var searchResults = Entities.Contacts.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(s));

        return searchResults;
    }
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong, please guide me on this. Thanks.

Edit : **Contact** is an entity model class generated by the EntityFramework and has one int field called 'id' and two string fields called 'city' and 'name'.

Comment: How does your `Contact` class look like?

Comment: Did u debug it ? U got the call on the controller ??

Comment: Can you post the actual code of the Contact class? Because I think your problem is with the the property name casing....

Comment: Yup ... U must have ! :P

Comment: solved ! needed to ouput json in a particular way only.. :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update : [Using jQuery Tokeninput with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor](http://yassershaikh.com/using-jquery-tokeninput-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor/)

Thanks @bhuvin and others.

Solved, had to do this...

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Search(string q)
{
    var searchResults = Helper.SearchContact(q);
    var jsonResult = searchResults.Select(results => new { id = results.Id, name = results.Name, city = results.City });
    return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and found this in TokenInput's documentation [here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).

Your script should output JSON search results in the following format:

```
[
    {"id":"856","name":"House"},
    {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**This works for me:**

In view:

```
<h2 id="theme">Facebook Theme</h2>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="authorlist" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("GetAuthors", "Home")" />

</div>
```

In script(javascript)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#authorlist").tokenInput("@Url.Action("Search")", {
            theme: "facebook",
            preventDuplicates: true
        });

    });
</script>
```

In controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Search(string q)
{
    q = q.ToUpper();
    var authors = db.StudentDB
        .Where(a => a.name.ToLower().StartsWith(q))
        .Select(a => new { id = a.id, name = a.name });

    return Json(authors,  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```